# Issue in XML parsing using SAX

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I have a XML which i am trying to parse.

```xml
<Tests>
   <Test>
     <Blocks>
         <Block>
            <BlockId>2</BlockId>
            <Name>CCCC</Name>
            <Type>Action</Type>
            <TaskId>2</TaskId>
            <Send>
               <WId>284</WId>
               <BlockId>14</BlockId>
            </Send>
         </Block>
         <Block>
            <BlockId>10</BlockId>
            <Name>START VM4</Name>
            <Type>Action</Type>
            <TaskId>10</TaskId>
            <Send />
         </Block>
         <Block>
            <BlockId>12</BlockId>
            <Name>SHUT</Name>
            <Type>Action</Type>
            <TaskId>12</TaskId>
            <Send />
         </Block>
     </Blocks>
 </Tests>
</Test>
```

I am using SAX to parse this.
Everything works fine, but every time i loop through, i should get a block with id 2 and then another block with blockid 10 and then 12. and i am then adding to all these blocks to the test.

Portion of my code is:

```java
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    nqName = qName;
    tag_name_List.setElementAt(nqName, level);
    level = level + 1;

}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {
    level = level - 1;
    tag_name_List.removeElementAt(level);
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (level != 0) {
        ////////////////Some code
    } else if (level == 5
            && tag_name_List.elementAt(1).equals("Test") 
            && tag_name_List.elementAt(2).equals("Blocks") 
            && tag_name_List.elementAt(3).equals("Block") 
            && (nqName.equalsIgnoreCase("BlockId"))) {
        block = new Block();
        test.addBlock(block);
        block.setId(new String(ch, start, length));
        block.setWorkflowId(workflow.getId());

    } else if (level == 5 && ...) {  
        ////// Code continues
```

NB This is a huge xml and huge code, so just sharing partly...

But the issue here is:

- the first time I get `id` as `2`,
- then     `"\n      "`
- then again `id` as `10`
- and then `"\n       "`
- then `id` `12`
- and then `"\n        "`.

I am not sure why i am getting these `"\n        "`.

I can put a `if` condition to avoid that entity, but if i do so i lose some information attached to that `id`, which later gets associated with that `"\n       "` `id`.

Has anyone faced this and can give a pointer.

Let me know if more information is needed.

After debugging the code i found that, it is basically taking the `"\n          "` from the end of

```xml
<BlockId>14</BlockId>
```

Since there will be a `\r` and `"\n      "` for the next line here.

How can i avoid this?

Comment: Please add your SAX handler implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign `nqName = qName`. Do you ever change that value until the next iteration?

If you don't change that value when you leave the context of the `BlockId` element, it will *still be equal to* `BlockId` when you are *outside* the element but not yet inside `Name`, for example. And the `characters()` method will read *all* the whitespace it finds there.

There should probably reset `nqName` in your `endElement()`. Try adding

```
nqName = null;
```

to your `endElement()` method.